# [slurm]How to check the job type on slurm ? batch or interactive

Tags: slurm

I want to determine whether a job on the slurm is a batch job or an interactive job.

It is possible to check the batch host with the following command, but is there a better way?

```
squeue -O "Name,BatchHost"
NAME                EXEC_HOST           
int                login001   
batch             compute009
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scontrol show job` has a flag `BatchFlag`. The `scontrol` manpage says:

> BatchFlag
>
> Jobs submitted using the sbatch command have BatchFlag set to 1.  Jobs submitted using other commands have BatchFlag set to 0.

Comment: Thank you for your corresponding. I was able to confirm.
It was also able to confirm by "squeue -O "BatchFlag" command.